# Pytest-html custom report

Tags: python, report, pytest, pytest-html

I'm using pytest to run my tests, and using pytest html to generate a report.

i'm trying to show the error\skip message in cases of failure or skip in the report, using the value form `call.excinfo.value`.
i notice that `pytest_runtest_makereport` is being called multiple times, for `setup`, `call` and `teardown`, and since `call.excinfo.value` in `setup` and `teardown` is null, it is overwriting the message in the cell, and as a result the `error message` cell is empty.

so, i tried to update the value with the following condition `report.when == "call"`,
but i'm getting the following error when `pytest_html_results_table_row` is executing on `setup` and `teardown`:

`AttributeError: 'TestReport' object has no attribute 'error_message'`

here is the code that i tried:

```
# in conftest.py
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.th('Error Message'))


@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.td(report.error_message))



@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    if report.when == "call" and report.skipped or report.failed:
        report.error_message = str(call.excinfo.value) if call.excinfo else ""
```

is there another way to show the error message in the report for failure\skipped.
p.s: for tests that are passed the value should be an empty string

here is what I expect to achieve:
[image: expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to solve this issue, i hope it will help someone in the future.
This is a workaround to handle the issue where `teardown` overwrites the value that was set during `call` phase.

basically, after the `teardown` phase i'm overwriting the value in the `error_message` with the value that was set during the `call` phase.

Note: please take in consideration that this will show only the error message from the `call` phase

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.error_message = ""


    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can be "setup", "call", "teardown"
    setattr(item, "rep_" + report.when, report)
    report.error_message = str(call.excinfo.value) if call.excinfo else ""
    if report.when == "teardown":
        # retrieving the error messages from the call phase
        report.error_message = item.rep_call.error_message
```

see image attached [report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1WUv.png)